# Flexbox doesn't work correctly(Dont Turn When i Hit M Screen size)

Tags: bootstrap-4

For Some reason when the screen size turn `md` I can't get two cols in one row, only when I hit small I get one col at each row (col-12), can someone tell me why? Tried anything, can't understand why it's not working.

```
<div class="row align-items-center" id="footerRow">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-stretch">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-m-6  mt-4 mb-4"dir="rtl">
                <img src="assets/logo.png" dir="rtl">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-m-6  mt-4 mb-4">
                <ul dir="rtl" class="footerUl">
                    <h5>צור קשר</h5>
                    <li>רחוב העצמאות 53 באר שבע</li>
                    <li>syllabus.uk@gmail.com</li>
                    <li>08-6201119</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-m-6 mt-4 mb-4">
                <ul dir="rtl" class="footerUl">
                    <li>מפת האתר</li>
                    <li><a href="#">דף הבית</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">אודות</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">המרכזים שלנו</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">תאריכים 2019</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">גלריה</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">צור קשר</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-m-6 mt-4 mb-4">
                <ul dir="rtl" class="footerUl">
                    <li>סאמר סקולס</li>
                        <li>סאמר סקול טיול לפריז</li>
                        <li>סאמר סקול אקסטרים</li>
                        <li>סאמר סקול קיימברידג'</li>
                        <li>סאמר סקול בניו יורק</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use `col-m-6`, use `col-md-6`.

**m** is use for `margin`.

for more info visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: don't forget to give upvote and valid answer by click in arrow, thanks